# Using command to find DIR name within USER folder

Tags: file, cmd, directory, copy

Im creating a .bat file to copy over a folder from the current directory into the USERS/???/AppData/Local/CourseWork/ folder

However there is no way of knowing what the name of the ??? folder will be as it will be a random students computer.

Is there any way Using Command (and my BAT file) To either retrieve said Folder name , Or copy the files into the Coursework Folder without knowing the ??? folder name.

i was hoping it would be as simple as

copy "Test.exe" "C:\USERS\ *.* \APPDATA\LOCAL\test.exe"

but unfortunatly it is not.

Iv also looked at Xcopy and robocopy but found no solution , not that there is no solution, i just have not yet found it...

Does anybody have any idea how they would work around this

My .bat file works fine for 1 set of folders & files but once it comes time for this particular folder (C:/USERS/???/APPDATA/LOCAL/COURSEWORK/), im very stuck on what to do for not knowing the name of the ??? folder or how to use Command to copy into the Coursework folder whilst bypassing the name of ???

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use the `%USERNAME%` variable or even better the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` variable

Comment: ok, will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the .bat file script is run when the user is logged in, then it is simple.

```
COPY ".\Test.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local"
```

If the .bat file script is run while logged in as a different user (ie. "teacher"), then the username must be known AND the "teacher" account must have permission to write into the user's directories.

Comment: ok. fortunatly its not going into Userprofile, Rather PCname? soi take it the command would be COPY ".\Test.exe" "%LOCALAPPDATA%\AppData\Local"

Comment: @ShaneDee, the `LOCALAPPDATA` variable already has `AppData\Local` in it. Use the `SET LOCALAPPDATA` command to see the current value.

Comment: Thank you. i eventually created a .exe file to execute what i required. Very greatfull